# Cura 3.2.1 raising segmentation faults

Tags: linux, python, arch-linux

When ever I start cura (whether as sudo or user) it raises a segmentation fault. I have no idea why. This happens on both my computer and laptop, both of which run Arch linux. Cura used to work on both systems before.

Error: https://pastebin.com/JvGvJBP3

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (even though I just installed Cura 3.2.1 in Arch Linux for the first time). I could at least work-around by downloading the AppImage Version of Cura from [their GitHub releases page](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/releases) and this is working so far.

This means it is probably an issue with any one of its dependencies that is not incompatible after an update.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Blackwood I know. I would have preferred to just add this as a comment but I have not yet enough reputation to do that. But also did not want to leave this without my workaround. And to be sassy, there is no question. ;-)